Vencord Installer
I am writing this as I am having an issue with the Vencord Installer in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS "Jammy Jellyfish" upon running the command
-c "$(curl -sS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Vendicated/VencordInstaller/main/install.sh
‎ ‎ ‎ ‎  I get the output Downloading Installer | Running With Sudo  After that It just goes back to Username@Pc-Name: $  and Never gives me a Prompt to enter Password or anything.
Note; After Writing this I tried it again and it did give me a Prompt to enter my password but after entering my Password it just went back to Username@Pc-Name: $| After I finished that I used the command Sudo -i to go into root and ran the command sudo apt install curl after that finished I went back into normal user and now I get no Output it's just -c "$(curl -sS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Vendicated/VencordInstaller/main/install.sh‎ and then >
Note; Upon thinking about it some more I went to the  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Vendicated/VencordInstaller/main/install.sh page and copied the bash Code and made a new .sh file named install.sh then I moved the file to the /usr/local/bin directory using sudo mv /home/username/Downloads/install.sh /usr/local/bin/ and then ran the sudo chmod -x /usr/local/bin/install.sh command to allow it to run and then ran install.sh and boom it worked
Issue #1 No Popup for Password After using sudo
Issue #2 | After Running command Output is just >
